# Beginner VPS Vultr/ServerPilot -> How to change the homepage & access the files I uploaded?

Tags: python, html, hosting, vps

So I just bought a VPS server from Vultr. Then I went on ServerPilot, and installed it on my server.

Now I can access, via SFTP, all the files on my server.

But how can I access these files from my web-browser via Internet? I mean, when I type in the IP address of my Vultr Server, I land on the ServerPilot page "your app xxx is set up". Alright, but how can I access the other files I uploaded now?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can connect to your server/serverpilot app via SSH/SFTP.

Filezilla, codeanywhere are options that allow you to do this.